# Compare two rows of SQL Hive array

Tags: sql, hive

Yesterday I was prompted for the code for Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
word1 VARCHAR[3],    
word2 VARCHAR[3]
);

INSERT INTO logs (Word1, Word2) VALUES 
  ('{"location","title","value"}', '{"moskow","title353","34"}'),
  ('{"title","value","location"}', '{"title5653","574584","sidney"}');
 
SELECT *, 
 array_position(Word1, 'location') location_position,
 Word2[array_position(Word1, 'location')] location_value
FROM logs;
```

The task was to find out the sequence number of the location value in the first one-dimensional array, and output the value with the same sequence number from the second array. The question is: how to remake the last part with array_position under Hive SQL?

I didn't find a function for the hive that would be similar to array_position in postgres, is it even possible to implement this in the hivegiven that the order and values in arrays can change, while their sequence is preserved in both arrays?

Comment: There are problems with your question: 1) a varchar[3] will hold any string up to 3 characters long, but no longer than that. 2) you are storing more than one data element in a single column in a table. Both these problems need to be solved before your question can be addressed. I would recommend breaking up the table into 3 columns. value (int), location (varchar[32]) and title (varchar[512]). The length of the varchars depends on how long any given string can possibly be that is inserted into the table. Read up on varchar vs char before making a decision on that.

Comment: Update your question. I left an open comment on the question as to how to get that done.